# Image highlighting effect

Tags: python, image, masking

I am studying image segmentation and have got some my simulation results.

I wonder how to generate an image as the attached one.
This figure is illustrated by the authors of the paper “Learning deep features from discriminative localization” whose well-known concept is class activation map (CAM) (Fig. 1 in the paper).

The images in first row are the input images and the images in second row are the output images.

In order to generate the output, the another input, an mask image, might be required.

The value of each pixel of the mask image ranges from 0 to 1.
The pixel whose value in mask is 1 will be colored red and 0 will be blue.

[image: Show the attached image]

I tried to find the method to do that but I have no idea what keyword I should use.

I also tried to find the way to compute the values of the output images but it was also ambiguous.

I thought the output can be generated by simple interpolation.
For example, if the value of mask is 1, I thought the output could be an average of original and [255,original,original] (RGB representation).

Can this be simply done using python?
The method indeed can be interpolation but I cannot find the exact values.

Any link of keyword to find out the way will be greatly thanksful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the "heatmap" is just being drawn with fixed transparency on top of the photo

to answer this I'd:

1. create a 2d `(x,y)` activation map; each value is the "activation" level at that pixel
2. transform this into a 3d `(x,y,rgb)` image through a [color map](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html); each value is turned into a RGB triple, e.g. 0=blue, 1=red in your example.  I'd also suggest using a different colormap, the example is particularly bad with respect to [perceptual uniformity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU)
3. use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to [`blend`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.blend) the map on top of the original

hope that helps!